# Is their a way to connect to windows azure database using SQL Workbench or management tool

Tags: sql, azure

Hello guys,
             Now its whole day ended and i am stuck where i was in morning..

I tried mostly lot of management tool and mysql workbench to connect to sql azure database so i can manage import / export database , tables and i can create dump of sql file for future use with my work and php projects.

but it was all helpless.. it does not connect to the db and to the azure server it seems azure are worst option.. :(

any suggestion will be helpful.

Always i get a new error code whenever i tried with SQL management tool 2005 and with MySQL workbench 5.x

Comment: Are you sure you opened the connection in Azure for your machine's IP address?

Comment: What are the error messages you are getting?

Comment: Yea i opened the IP for my machine .. and also i double checked the port in my machine for blockage. but its all good to go.

Comment: will let you know error messages in some hours when i wake up.

Comment: Please clarify which tool you're trying to use. You mentioned three different names: [SQL Workbench](http://www.sql-workbench.net/databases.html), [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) and "SQL management tool 2005" which I assume would be [SQL Server Management Studio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Management_Studio). And what "Azure Database" are you trying to connect to? MySQL or SQL Database (formerly known as SQL Azure)?

Answer (score 1):

Is your port 1433 open?

I would rather recommend a newer version of SQL management tool. Maybe an express version. SSMS 2012 Express supports special Azure SQL options like "Deploy Database to SQL Azure" etc, whereas SSMS 2005 seems very out of date.

I am not sure but does MySQL Workbench supports MSSQL anyways? I don't think so, but have not tried yet!

Comment: I don't think port 1433 needs to be open. He is connecting to a remote database, not hosting the database on his machine.